how to check if two LR(1) parsing tables are identical in function?
I'm making an LR(1) parser generator, and want to validate it. My parser generator sorts the stuff differently so some states are identical to the reference output, but some are assigned to different states, so state 7 in reference would be like state 9 in my implementation due to how the terminals and non-terminals are ordered. I want to know how to check if two different parsing tables are identical in how they work.
Also on a side note, are there any resources to testing LR(1) parser generators, like complex grammars (preferably without epsilons as mine doesn't support epsilons yet) and their respective outputs?
I don't know how to approach this so any help would be greatly appreciated. But perhaps I can do something like test every possible input and store the states and maybe check that but I don't know how to approach that and solve it without infinite loops (in cases for lists)

This is a graph isomorphism problem. A LALR(1) table is a kind of graph; you are asking, are these two graphs the same? If your algorithm is producing the graph in a sufficiently similar way (e.g. order of states), except for some details like numbering, you could try to fudge things by adding a renumbering pass to match the reference.

Start with the starting state of each table.
Check that they have actions on the same set of symbols. (If not, abort with failure.)
Then, for each such symbol, get each table's action on that symbol, and compare them. They should either be:

both reduce actions, reducing by the same production, or
both shift actions, but with possibly different next-state-numbers. Make a note that state x in the reference table corresponds to state y in your table. (You don't yet know that they're the same, but you know that, if the two tables are equivalent, then these states must be the same. So assume they are and look for a contradiction.) Then recurse, comparing those two states. Or if, in future, you discover that you've already noted that correspondence, skip the recursion. Or if you find yourself about to make a contradictory correspondence, abort with failure.

Ultimately, you'll either abort with failure, or you'll pop out of the recursive calls and end up with a complete correspondence between the state-numbers of the two tables.
(That's a depth-first traversal. You could also do it as a breadth-first traversal.)
